# How to place card over image in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm now working on a website. I tried several times to place the card over the picture. Can you have any suggestions?https://i.stack.imgur.com/goigA.png

Answer (score 1):

one way is set minus `margin-top` for example: `margin-top : -100px`

```css
.tag {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.d-flex{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png">
    <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```